# D3 Comparison bar chart

Tags: json, d3.js

```
var data = [
    {"Month":"2013/12","Name":"John","EC":344},
    {"Month":"2013/12","Name":"Smith","EC":249},
    {"Month":"2013/12","Name":"Mary","EC":161},    
    {"Month":"2013/11","Name":"John","EC":128},
    {"Month":"2013/11","Name":"Smith","EC":125},  
    {"Month":"2013/11","Name":"Mary","EC":117}
];
```

I have json data for 3 people John, Smith & Mary for the month of 2013/11 and 2013/12. I want to draw d3 bar chart to compare the data of each person for the month 2013/11 and 2013/12 by representing each person with different bar color for both months. The same set of  colors will be used for each person for both months.

How do I group by Name and draw bars for their count (EC) for both the month(11 &12) of the same person. I only get one bar but the other bar does not come up for each person. My code is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4gY8H/. Can you please help me figure out what I am missing?

```
var data=[{"Name":"Katte","Month":"2013/11","ExamCount":"30"},{"Name":"Borsh","Month":"2013/11","ExamCount":"130"},{"Name":"Broer","Month":"2013/11","ExamCount":"320"},{"Name":"John","Month":"2013/11","ExamCount":"60"},
{"Name":"Katte","Month":"2013/12","ExamCount":"130"},{"Name":"Borsh","Month":"2013/12","ExamCount":"1130"},{"Name":"Broer","Month":"2013/12","ExamCount":"3120"},{"Name":"John","Month":"2013/12","ExamCount":"610"}];
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["rgba(11,94,215,.8)", "rgba(245, 143, 8, 0.8)", "rgba(0, 167, 188, 0.8)", "rgba(223, 40, 35, 0.8)", "rgba(153, 44, 150, 0.8)", "rgba(124, 189, 42, 0.8)", "rgba(37, 47, 71, 0.8)","rgba(153, 0, 51, 0.8)", "rgba(153, 51, 51, 0.8)", "rgba(92, 0, 92, 0.8)"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  var months = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Name"; });
console.log(months);
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.month = months.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Name; }));
  x1.domain(months).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.month, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Exam Count");

  var person = svg.selectAll(".person")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Name) + ",0)"; });

  person.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.month; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(months.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
</script>
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html)?

Comment: like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152, but I am not sure how to draw the same with data I have.

Comment: I kind of fixed it . It shows as stacked bar's but not sure how to have separate bars for each month grouped by person name. But not sure how to get 2 bars for each month for each person. My code is updated here. http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/

Comment: You should really try to understand the code line by line. While D3 might seem odd at first, it's quite simple once you get over yourself and try to understand it. It's also incredibly powerful.

Comment: I am a newbie to D3 and trying to see if D3 fits my needs. So I am exploring and seems to be overwhelming at present.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you basically copied [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051), but the data format is different.
For example, you do:

```
var months = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Name"; });
```

With your data that returns `["Month", "ExamCount"]` instead of the months.
In your case, you could use:

```
var months = d3.set(data.map(function(line) { return line.Month; })).values();
```

which returns `["2013/11", "2013/12"]`

There are other examples. Why do you have 8 colors if you only need 2?
And the entire data binding part (when you create a rect for every data line) is wrong for your data structure, you should try to write it from scratch instead of trying to adapt the one from the example (which has data in CSV format, very different).

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxW9T/17/